# Numerical double integrals using Gauss–Legendre Quadrature in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve double integrals through Gauss–Legendre Quadrature numeric method in python without using any library that has numeric methods. But i can't make the algorithm work when I have functions as the limits of integration. This is what I tried:

```
def integrate(a: float, b: float, n: int, f_xy: callable, upper_func: callable, lower_func: callable) -> float:

    if n < 1:
        raise("n < 1 is invalid.")

    w, t = get_wt(n)

    e1_x = (b-a)/2
    e2_x = (a+b)/2
    sum = 0

    for i in range(n):

        x_i = e1_x*t[i]+e2_x

        if type(upper_func) == int:
            d = upper_func
        else:
            d = upper_func(x_i)

        if type(lower_func) == int:
            c = lower_func
        else:
            c = lower_func(x_i)

        e1_y = (d - c)/2
        e2_y = (c + d)/2

        som = 0
        for j in range(n):
            y_i = e1_y*t[j]+e2_y
            som += w[j]*f_xy(x_i, y_i)

        sum += w[i]*som

    result = (1/4)*(b-a)*(d-c)*sum

    return result
```

where the `get_wt()` function returns the weights and nodes.

---

[Edit]

I managed to do it. It only needed a couple tweaks.

```
def double_integrate(a: float, b: float, n: int, f_xy: Union[Callable, float],
                     up_func: Union[Callable, float], low_func: Union[Callable, float]) -> float:
     
    w, t = get_wt(n)

    e1_x = (b-a)/2
    e2_x = (a+b)/2

    sum = 0

    for i in range(n):

        som = 0

        x_i = e1_x*t[i]+e2_x

        if not isfunction(up_func):
            d = up_func
        else:
            d = up_func(x_i)

        if not isfunction(low_func):
            c = low_func
        else:
            c = low_func(x_i)

        e1_y = (d - c)/2
        e2_y = (c + d)/2

        for j in range(n):
            y_i = e1_y*t[j]+e2_y

            if isfunction(f_xy):
                som += w[j]*f_xy(x_i, y_i)
            else:
                som += w[j]*f_xy

        sum += w[i]*e1_y*som

    result = e1_x*sum

    return result
```

Comment: I don't believe Gaussian quadrature is appropriate when the limits are functions.  The region you're integrating over has to be bounded.

Comment: But it's bounded, between the given c(x) and d(x) functions (considering c and d as the inner limits).

Answer (score 1):

In your algorithm, the line

```
result = (1/4)*(b-a)*(d-c)*sum
```

is not correct. It should be aligned with the return statement ;). Also, the formula you are using has a conceptual mistake. Considering that your algorithm works, it can only solve double integrals over rectangles, meaning the variables `c` and `d` are constants. However, if you want integrate over a more complex region, where the variables `c` and `d` are functions, `(c + d)/2` should be integrated in the outer integral.
If you wanna try to implement it, I would recommend you transform this integral [this double integral](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cbegin%7Balign*%7D%5Cint%5Eb_%7Ba%7D%5Cint%5E%7Bg(x)%7D_%7Bh(x)%7Df(x,%20y)dydx%5Cend%7Balign*%7D) into an integral over a square [-1,1]x[-1,1] by hand. Doing so might give you clarity on how to implement this algorithm.